# How to add multiple filters when searching Stack Overflow questions under a tag?

Tags: discussion, search

Let's say that I would like to search for questions under a specific tag by the following filtering steps:

1. List all questions within the last 1 months.
2. Keep only the questions that are unanswered.
3. Sort them by vote.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What have you tried? What link/page/route are you using?

Comment: This is the page I am monitoring: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/google-cloud-spanner

I can filter in all the unanswered questions, but there is no way to sort by vote and then by time. I have to pick either "Newest" or "Votes"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer to [the "How do I search?" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

You would use the `hasaccepted:no` and `created:1m..` parameters.

Like so:
  [`[google-cloud-spanner] hasaccepted:no created:1m..`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-spanner%5D%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20created%3A1m..&mixed=0)

Direct link to the votes tab:
  [/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-spanner%5d%20hasaccepted%3ano%20created%3a1m..](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-spanner%5D%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20created%3A1m..)

---

If you mean the question must have no answers at all, then that is:

- [[google-cloud-spanner] answers:0 created:1m..](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-spanner%5D%20answers%3A0%20created%3A1m..&mixed=0)

Comment: He's asking for "unanswered" not "unaccepted". There's probably a parameter for that to.

Comment: @Adriaan Mybe `answers:0` or `isanswered:`

Comment: @Adriaan, given the OP's confusion (originally tagged as API, for example), it's not clear *what* he means by unanswered.  I went with the "street" definition.  If he means something else, there's a parameter for that.

Comment: @BrockAdams No, here is an example `[subquery]isanswered:false`

Comment: `created:1m` is not a good option, there is questions which created long time does not have answers.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [boolean operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) you can use them to search in the site.

Here is an example to search non answered questions for [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server):

```
[sql-server]isanswered:false answers:0
```

Or this way to exclude the closed posts:

```
[sql-server]isanswered:false answers:0 closed:false
```